# Test for existence of (wildcard) files in R

Tags: r

I am doing something like

```
    EPP = list.files(pattern = "log.*.*csv*") %>% 
      map_df(~read_csv(., show_col_types = FALSE)) %>% 
      distinct()
```

which works, reading both csv.gz and csv, and am wondering how to check whether there are any *.csv.gz or *.csv before reading all (both types) of them (if any) as above, by way of an

```
    if () {} else {}
```

block, so I can proceed if no files of either type are found.

Thanks in advance, el

Comment: `if (length(EPP) > 0) {...} else {...}`?

Comment: rather off-topic, but I think you should improve your pattern-regex. I'd suggest: "^log.*\\.csv(\\.gz)?$" meaning: filename starts with "log" and ends with ".csv" (or ".csv.gz")

Comment: Thank you.

This quite helpful, actually. 

I'll try my hand figuring out how to put this

03-2[23456789]-2020.csv 0[456789]-??-2020.csv 1*2020.csv *202[123456789]*csv

into a regex this weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break down your code in two steps.

```
library(tidyverse)

files = list.files(pattern = "log.*.*csv*")

if(length(files)) 
  EPP <- files %>% map_df(~read_csv(., show_col_types = FALSE)) %>% distinct()
```

Comment: So simple sometimes but so far. Had not though of length(). That'll do just fine. Thank you.